# How can I use tweepy without a filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

I'm new to the `tweepy` library.  I am able to capture a twitter stream if I use a filter like the one shown below, looking for tweets containing the word snow in the text field.

```
import tweepy
ckey = ''
csecret = ''
atoken = ''
asecret = ''
auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["snow"])
```

However, I don't know how to capture all tweets without doing any filtering.  If I leave off the last line of the above code, the program runs, but I don't get any tweets.  If I change the track parameter to `track=[]` or `track=[""]`, I receive an error code of 406 from the Twitter API.

I am using Python 3.4.2.

Comment: Thanks, wnnmaw, for the formatting help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `twitterStream.sample()` as the last line for that. It will fetch all the tweets for you.

Comment: It won't fetch all the tweets.

"Returns a **small random sample** of all public statuses. The Tweets returned by the default access level are the same, so if two different clients connect to this endpoint, they will see the same Tweets."

[link](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/sample-realtime/overview/GET_statuse_sample)

Comment: The new api states this:

"The sampled stream endpoint allows developers to stream about 1% of all new public Tweets as they happen. You can connect no more than one client per session, and can disconnect and reconnect no more than 50 times per 15 minute window." [link](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/labs/sampled-stream/overview)

Answer (score 2):

Dont do a search by location. It would limit out those tweets which dont have geolocation enabled. What I suggest is to use stream.sample() instead. IT doesnt have any necessary parameters. See tweepy docs for more info.

Answer (score 0):

the streaming API can only be used with at least one predicate parameter, as specified in the twitter [documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter).
luckily, there's also a `locations` parameter, and you can pass the value `[-180,-90,180,90]` to get tweets from every point on earth.

so, in your snippet above, the last line should be:
`twitterStream.filter(locations=[-180,-90,180,90])`

the only filtering you'll get is that the user must not have turned the geotagging off.